# Did I blow the motor of my table saw?

Tags: electric-motor, table-saw

Cutting some cedar and overworking my Dewalt 10" portable table saw and it slowed down and then shut off. I let it cool for hours, cleaned it of dust and debris, tried another outlet and it has not come back on. It is a 2015 model and doesn't have a reset button or switch on the motor. Did I blow the motor? Do I have to purchase a $110 motor from DeWalt? Is there a way to check for a guy that knows squat?

Comment: You probably didn't "blow the motor" (not really a thing with electrics), but you may have scorched the brushes. Are there user-serviceable slotted caps on the sides?

Comment: Maybe post the motor model number. The year probably isn't important.

Comment: Did the motor "smoke" or just get hot, small motors are required to have thermal overloads some automatically reset some you have to push a button. If you have a ohm meter unplug and put the leads on the flat blades of the plug then turn the switch on there should be a fairly low resistance, if not turn the motor a little if no resistance it could be a overload device or brushes if it has brushes. What is the model number?

Comment: DWE 7491 is the saw. I'd have to check the motor.

Comment: Genuine DeWalt replacement part
1 Carbon Brush with wire lead and brush spring

Comment: I got two of the brushes and installed them (quickly) into the motor. Although the old ones appeared ok, they apparently were not. The new brushes were the solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

First call tech line about the situation with Dewalt.  Also look for overload reset button.  That motor should be protected from just such situations.